# Sharing generic.xaml across multiple assemblies

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am creating a set of controls that I wish to use in both a Silverlight and Windows Phone deployment.  The core controls are contained within a WP7 class library, which can be used by both deployments.  I then have platform specific controls contained in further WP7 and Silverlight libraries.

For the shared controls, I need to define a different default style for each platform. From what I've been reading the generic.xaml needs to be in the same assembly as the controls it's styling.

How would I approach this to be able to define a resource for a control in my WP7 assembly, and another resource for the same control in my Silverlight assembly while the control itself is in another shared assembly?

Comment: I have tried creating the generic.xaml in the platform specific assembly, but the style doesn't get loaded and OnApplyTemplate is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the generic.xaml from my assembly into the App.Resources works fine. Works in the App.xaml and by programatically adding the merged resource dictionary.